# middleware running after views' route method

Tags: django, django-middleware

My middleware is as follows :

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',

    # My custom middleware where I have set request.foo = "bar"
    'application.custom_middleware.CustomMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

But when doing a print of `request.foo` I get it printed correctly in the middleware but in the views function it throws.

```
    print("request.foo = ", request.foo)
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'foo'
request.foo in custom_middleware = bar
```

My views's add function is as follows :

```
@ms_identity_web.login_required
def add(request):
    print("request.foo in add = ", request.foo)
```

Django 4.2.5

Comment: Have you tried to add `application.custom_middleware.CustomMiddleware` after all the other values of `MIDDLEWARE` list?